# PHP startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_ssh2

Tags: php, dll, ssh, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to install php_ssh2 extension on wamp.
I do the following things:

1. copy libssh2.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
2. register the dll file: Regsvr32 libssh2.dll
3. copy php_ssh2.dll to  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext
4. add extension line in php.ini

i got the message:

[image]

Hope if someone will know to help ! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the 32bit or 64 bit WampServer?

Comment: I am using 64bit WampServer

Answer (score 1):

The libssh2.dll does not need all that doing to it.

**As a simple rule of thumb when using WAMPServer, nothing needs to be placed into the `C:\windows\....` folders. If you do you destroy the ability to switch versions of Apache/PHP/MySQL at the click of a link** which is afterall one of the primary reason to use WAMPServer over other similiar products.

**How To Install the SSH2 PHP Extension to WAMPServer.**

DOWNLOAD the SSH2 extension [from here](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)

- click on the word 'DLL' next to the windows icon to get to the windows builds.

For WAMPServer you will need the TS ( Thread Safe ) versions
Download the Thread Safe version that matches your WAMPServer i.e. 32bit/64bit and the major version of PHP you want to install it into i.e. PHP5.4 or PHP5.5 etc.

If you are running 32bit WAMPServer even on a 64bit Windows you should be using the 32bit (x86) version of ssh2!

Using wampmanager, stop all services

`wampmanager -> Stop all Services`

Extract these 2 files from the zip (rememeber the SSH2 files are specific to a version of PHP, so make sure you use the correct zip file).

```
copy libssh2.dll to \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\
copy php_ssh2.dll to \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\ext
```

Edit php.ini ( using the wampmanager menus )

`wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini`

Locate the section containing the extension parameters and add this line

```
extension=php_ssh2.dll
```

IF you are using **WAMPServer 2.5.15 or later** you can **skip this next step** as it has already been incorporated into the WAMPServer refresh process.

IF you are using WAMPServer 2.5 or older versions :

Edit \wamp\scripts\config.inc.php
Find this section of the file,

```
$phpDllToCopy = array (
```

And add this line into the array, it can go anywhere in that list

```
$phpDllToCopy = array (
    'libssh2.dll',
```

Start all the services again

```
wampmanager -> Start all Services
```

Look at

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions
```

You should see php_ssh2 in the list with a tick beside it.

Now you need to get WAMPManager to rebuild the SYMLINKS into the \apachex.y.z\bin folder. So using the wampamanager menus DO:

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9    

( click on the version number, it may or may not be 2.4.9 )
```

This should take a few second and then you are ready to test that ssh2 is loaded.

Now launch localhost

```
wampmanager -> localhost
```

On the homepage you should see `ssh2` in the list of `Loaded Services`

[image]

Click the `phpinfo()` link on the WAMPServer homepage and you should see the following information proving that SSH2 has been loaded

[image]

**Now if you want to use SSH2 from PHP used at the command line ( PHP CLI ) then you need to do one more thing.**

Edit \wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini

Locate the section containing the extension parameters and add this line

```
extension=php_ssh2.dll
```

You are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am looking in php_info() -> "Registered PHP Streams" and i don't see following ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp, i see just php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar

Comment: Have you undone all the stuff you did earlier? Have you got the correct version of `SSH2` that matches your `PHP` version? Have you removed `libssh2.dll from C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and unregistered is as a service?

Comment: Yes, the main issue is "Call to undefined function ssh2_exec" and it caused by wrong installation in my opinion.

Comment: I amended my answer after looking a little closer as the problem. I just tested this so it should now be a complete solution. I HOPE?

Comment: Thanks for the link for ssh2. All the other answers everywhere had old links and I just couldn't find one for php 7.2

Answer (score 1):

libssh2 is a PITA. I'd just use phpseclib's libssh2-compatibility-layer:

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer

Example:

```
<?php
include('phpseclib.php');

$ssh = ssh2_connect('www.domain.tld');
echo ssh2_fingerprint($ssh);
```

Basically, it just uses phpseclib to emulate all of the ssh2_* functions.