# Fail to locate libssh2_scp_recv2 in dynamic link library c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.31\ext\phpcurl.dll

Tags: php, dll

I am trying install php_ssh2 extension on my wampserver(32bits, php5.6.31) based on the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718077/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php-ssh2)
So, I had downloaded the SSH2 extension *php_ssh2-0.12-5.5-ts-vc11-x86* and 
copy *libssh2.dll* to *wamp\bin\php\phpx5.6.31*
and *php_ssh2.dll* to *\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.31\ext.*

I have also updated the **php.ini** by adding `extension=php_ssh2.dll`
Then, I can see that "php_ssh2" is ticked in my php_extension. However when I try to rebuild the SYMLINKS into the *\apache2.4.27\bin* folder.

I keep getting this error:

> The procedure entry point libssh2_scp_recv2 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.31\ext\phpcurl.dll.

Comment: You are using PHP 5.6... and trying to include a DLL for 5.5. You will need the 5.6 SSH2 dll. This is a requirement for pretty much any extension dll. They will not work with any other version (Major.Minor)

Comment: @DevionNL In part you are right. But in mi case I use the library from PHP 5.6 in PHP 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 with NO PROBLEM. In mi case when I switched to PHP 8 I got this error. In conclusion I think ... when have major changes in one library we need to update it

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue when I switched to PHP 8 (on apache 2.4)
I solved them in 2 steps:

**1. IMPORTANT:** Make a copy of `libssh2.dll` and `nghttp2.dll` from `Your_apache_folder\bin\` (in case something goes wrong, you can restore them)
If you cannot see it in `Your_apache_folder\bin\` then jump to second step.

**2. Copy paste** copy `libssh2.dll` and  `nghttp2.dll` from `your php folder` and paste both in `Your_apache_folder\bin\`

*Normally this should work. At least it worked for me*

Don't forget to restart apache:

- Open windows command line (cmd)
- Go to your installation folder of apache:
- `cd your\folder\apache\bin` + Enter
- Type: `httpd.exe -k restart` + Enter
- **Enjoy** :)